# Removing ambiguity in antlr4 lexing

Tags: antlr4

I've been trying to convert a grammar that I have found online into an antlr4 format.  The original grammar is here: https://github.com/cv/asp-parser/blob/master/vbscript.bnf.

Short Version:
The current problem that I am running across I think is due to ambiguity at the lexing stage.

For example, I copied the rule for a floating point literal as below:

```
float_literal   : DIGIT* '.' DIGIT+ ( 'e' PLUS_OR_MINUS? DIGIT+ )?
               | DIGIT+ 'e' PLUS_OR_MINUS? DIGIT+;
```

Further up in the file I have a definition for letters:

```
LETTER: 'a'..'z';
```

It seems that because I am using 'e' in the float literal, that character can't be recognised as a letter?  In my research I have come across the idea of having a token for each letter, so letter would become:

```
letter: A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z;
```

And I would replace any instances of 'e' with E.  However there are much longer strings in this file, such as '.and'.  So this approach would require replacing things like that with DOT A N D?  Which doesn't seem right at all.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or is there something I can do to avoid this ambiguity?

Thanks,
Craig

The full grammar is below.

```
grammar vbscript;
/*===== Character Sets =====*/

SPACES: ' ' -> skip;

DIGIT: '0'..'9';
SEMI_COLON: ':';
NEW_LINE_CHARACTER: [\r\n]+;
WHITESPACE_CHARACTER: [ \t];
LETTER: 'a'..'z';
QUOTE: '"';
HASH: '#';
SQUARE_BRACE: '[' | ']';
PLUS_OR_MINUS: [+-];
ANYTHING_ELSE: ~('"' | '#');
ws: WHITESPACE_CHARACTER;
id_tail: (DIGIT | LETTER | '_');
string_character: ANYTHING_ELSE | DIGIT | WHITESPACE_CHARACTER | SEMI_COLON | LETTER | PLUS_OR_MINUS | SQUARE_BRACE;
id_name_char: ANYTHING_ELSE | DIGIT | WHITESPACE_CHARACTER | SEMI_COLON | LETTER | PLUS_OR_MINUS;


/*===== terminals =====*/
whitespace: ws+ | '_' ws* new_line?;

comment_line   : '' | 'rem';

string_literal  : '"' ( string_character | '""' )* '"';

float_literal   : DIGIT* '.' DIGIT+ ( 'e' PLUS_OR_MINUS? DIGIT+ )?
               | DIGIT+ 'e' PLUS_OR_MINUS? DIGIT+;
id             : LETTER id_tail*
               | '[' id_name_char* ']';
iddot          : LETTER id_tail* '.'
               | '[' id_name_char* ']' '.'
               | 'and.'
               | 'byref.'
               | 'byval.'
               | 'call.'
               | 'case.'
               | 'class.'
               | 'const.'
               | 'default.'
               | 'dim.'
               | 'do.'
               | 'each.'
               | 'else.'
               | 'elseif.'
               | 'empty.'
               | 'end.'
               | 'eqv.'
               | 'erase.'
               | 'error.'
               | 'exit.'
               | 'explicit.'
               | 'false.'
               | 'for.'
               | 'function.'
               | 'get.'
               | 'goto.'
               | 'if.'
               | 'imp.'
               | 'in.'
               | 'is.'
               | 'let.'
               | 'loop.'
               | 'mod.'
               | 'new.'
               | 'next.'
               | 'not.'
               | 'nothing.'
               | 'null.'
               | 'on.'
               | 'option.'
               | 'or.'
               | 'preserve.'
               | 'private.'
               | 'property.'
               | 'public.'
               | 'redim.'
               | 'rem.'
               | 'resume.'
               | 'select.'
               | 'set.'
               | 'step.'
               | 'sub.'
               | 'then.'
               | 'to.'
               | 'true.'
               | 'until.'
               | 'wend.'
               | 'while.'
               | 'with.'
               | 'xor.';

dot_id          : '.' LETTER id_tail*
               | '.' '[' id_name_char* ']'
               | '.and'
               | '.byref'
               | '.byval'
               | '.call'
               | '.case'
               | '.class'
               | '.const'
               | '.default'
               | '.dim'
               | '.do'
               | '.each'
               | '.else'
               | '.elseif'
               | '.empty'
               | '.end'
               | '.eqv'
               | '.erase'
               | '.error'
               | '.exit'
               | '.explicit'
               | '.false'
               | '.for'
               | '.function'
               | '.get'
               | '.goto'
               | '.if'
               | '.imp'
               | '.in'
               | '.is'
               | '.let'
               | '.loop'
               | '.mod'
               | '.new'
               | '.next'
               | '.not'
               | '.nothing'
               | '.null'
               | '.on'
               | '.option'
               | '.or'
               | '.preserve'
               | '.private'
               | '.property'
               | '.public'
               | '.redim'
               | '.rem' 
               | '.resume'
               | '.select'
               | '.set'
               | '.step'
               | '.sub'
               | '.then'
               | '.to'
               | '.true'
               | '.until'
               | '.wend'
               | '.while'
               | '.with'
               | '.xor';

dot_iddot      : '.' LETTER id_tail* '.'
               | '.' '[' id_name_char* ']' '.'
               | '.and.'
               | '.byref.'
               | '.byval.'
               | '.call.'
               | '.case.'
               | '.class.'
               | '.const.'
               | '.default.'
               | '.dim.'
               | '.do.'
               | '.each.'
               | '.else.'
               | '.elseif.'
               | '.empty.'
               | '.end.'
               | '.eqv.'
               | '.erase.'
               | '.error.'
               | '.exit.'
               | '.explicit.'
               | '.false.'
               | '.for.'
               | '.function.'
               | '.get.'
               | '.goto.'
               | '.if.'
               | '.imp.'
               | '.in.'
               | '.is.'
               | '.let.'
               | '.loop.'
               | '.mod.'
               | '.new.'
               | '.next.'
               | '.not.'
               | '.nothing.'
               | '.null.'
               | '.on.'
               | '.option.'
               | '.or.'
               | '.preserve.'
               | '.private.'
               | '.property.'
               | '.public.'
               | '.redim.'
               | '.rem.'
               | '.resume.'
               | '.select.'
               | '.set.'
               | '.step.'
               | '.sub.'
               | '.then.'
               | '.to.'
               | '.true.'
               | '.until.'
               | '.wend.'
               | '.while.'
               | '.with.'
               | '.xor.';

/*===== rules =====*/
new_line: (SEMI_COLON | NEW_LINE_CHARACTER)+;
program: new_line? global_stmt_list;

/*===== rules: declarations =====*/
class_decl: 'class' extended_id new_line member_decl_list 'end' 'class' new_line;
member_decl_list: member_decl*;
member_decl: field_decl | var_decl | const_decl | sub_decl | function_decl | property_decl;
field_decl: 
  'private' field_name other_vars_opt new_line 
| 'public'  field_name other_vars_opt new_line;
field_name: field_id '(' array_rank_list ')' | field_id;
field_id: id | 'default' | 'erase' | 'error' | 'explicit' | 'step';
var_decl: 'dim' var_name other_vars_opt new_line;
var_name: extended_id '(' array_rank_list ')' | extended_id;
other_vars_opt: (',' var_name other_vars_opt)?;
array_rank_list: (int_literal ',' array_rank_list | int_literal)?;
const_decl: access_modifier_opt 'const' const_list new_line;
const_list: extended_id '=' const_expr_def ',' const_list | extended_id  '=' const_expr_def;
const_expr_def: '(' const_expr_def ')' 
| '-' const_expr_def
| '+' const_expr_def
| const_expr;
sub_decl: 
  method_access_opt 'sub' extended_id method_arg_list new_line method_stmt_list 'end' 'sub' new_line
| method_access_opt 'sub' extended_id method_arg_list inline_stmt 'end' 'sub' new_line;
function_decl: 
  method_access_opt 'function' extended_id method_arg_list new_line method_stmt_list 'end' 'function' new_line
| method_access_opt 'function' extended_id method_arg_list inline_stmt 'end' 'function' new_line;
method_access_opt: 'public' 'default' | access_modifier_opt;
access_modifier_opt: ('public' | 'private')?;
method_arg_list: ('(' arg_list? ')')?;
arg_list: arg (',' arg_list)?;
arg: arg_modifier_opt extended_id ('(' ')')?;
arg_modifier_opt: ('byval' | 'byref')?;
property_decl: method_access_opt 'property' property_access_type extended_id method_arg_list new_line method_stmt_list 'end' 'property' new_line;
property_access_type: 'get' | 'let' | 'set';

/*===== rules: statements =====*/
global_stmt: option_explicit | class_decl | field_decl | const_decl | sub_decl | function_decl | block_stmt;
method_stmt: const_decl | block_stmt;
block_stmt: 
  var_decl 
| redim_stmt 
| if_stmt 
| with_stmt 
| select_stmt 
| loop_stmt 
| for_stmt 
| inline_stmt new_line;
inline_stmt: 
  assign_stmt 
| call_stmt 
| sub_call_stmt 
| error_stmt 
| exit_stmt 
| 'erase' extended_id;
global_stmt_list: global_stmt_list global_stmt | global_stmt;
method_stmt_list: method_stmt*;
block_stmt_list: block_stmt*;
option_explicit: 'option' 'explicit' new_line;
error_stmt: 'on' 'error' 'resume' 'next' | 'on' 'error' 'goto' int_literal;
exit_stmt: 'exit' 'do' | 'exit' 'for' | 'exit' 'function' | 'exit' 'property' | 'exit' 'sub';
assign_stmt: 
        left_expr '=' expr 
| 'set' left_expr '=' expr 
| 'set' left_expr '=' 'new' left_expr;
sub_call_stmt:             qualified_id sub_safe_expr? comma_expr_list
                         | qualified_id sub_safe_expr?
                         | qualified_id '(' expr ')' comma_expr_list
                         | qualified_id '(' expr ')'
                         | qualified_id '(' ')'
                         | qualified_id index_or_params_list '.' left_expr_tail sub_safe_expr? comma_expr_list
                         | qualified_id index_or_params_list_dot left_expr_tail sub_safe_expr? comma_expr_list
                         | qualified_id index_or_params_list '.' left_expr_tail sub_safe_expr?
                         | qualified_id index_or_params_list_dot left_expr_tail sub_safe_expr?;


call_stmt: 'call' left_expr;

left_expr: qualified_id index_or_params_list '.' left_expr_tail
                         | qualified_id index_or_params_list_dot left_expr_tail
                         | qualified_id index_or_params_list
                         | qualified_id
                         | safe_keyword_id;

left_expr_tail: qualified_id_tail index_or_params_list '.' left_expr_tail
                         | qualified_id_tail index_or_params_list_dot left_expr_tail
                         | qualified_id_tail index_or_params_list
                         | qualified_id_tail;

qualified_id: iddot qualified_id_tail
                         | dot_iddot qualified_id_tail
                         | id
                         | dot_id;

qualified_id_tail: iddot qualified_id_tail
                         | id
                         | keyword_id;

keyword_id: safe_keyword_id
                         | 'and'
                         | 'byref'
                         | 'byval'
                         | 'call'
                         | 'case'
                         | 'class'
                         | 'const'
                         | 'dim'
                         | 'do'
                         | 'each'
                         | 'else'
                         | 'elseif'
                         | 'empty'
                         | 'end'
                         | 'eqv'
                         | 'exit'
                         | 'false'
                         | 'for'
                         | 'function'
                         | 'get'
                         | 'goto'
                         | 'if'
                         | 'imp'
                         | 'in'
                         | 'is'
                         | 'let'
                         | 'loop'
                         | 'mod'
                         | 'new'
                         | 'next'
                         | 'not'
                         | 'nothing'
                         | 'null'
                         | 'on'
                         | 'option'
                         | 'or'
                         | 'preserve'
                         | 'private'
                         | 'public'
                         | 'redim'
                         | 'resume'
                         | 'select'
                         | 'set'
                         | 'sub'
                         | 'then'
                         | 'to'
                         | 'true'
                         | 'until'
                         | 'wend'
                         | 'while'
                         | 'with'
                         | 'xor';

safe_keyword_id: 'default'
                         | 'erase'
                         | 'error'
                         | 'explicit'
                         | 'property'
                         | 'step';

extended_id: safe_keyword_id
                         | id;

index_or_params_list: index_or_params index_or_params_list
                         | index_or_params;

index_or_params: '(' expr comma_expr_list ')'
                         | '(' comma_expr_list ')'
                         | '(' expr ')'
                         | '(' ')';

index_or_params_list_dot: index_or_params index_or_params_list_dot
                         | index_or_params_dot;

index_or_params_dot: '(' expr comma_expr_list ').'
                         | '(' comma_expr_list ').'
                         | '(' expr ').'
                         | '(' ').';

comma_expr_list: ',' expr comma_expr_list
                         | ',' comma_expr_list
                         | ',' expr
                         | ',';

/* redim statement */

redim_stmt: 'redim' redim_decl_list new_line
                         | 'redim' 'preserve' redim_decl_list new_line;

redim_decl_list: redim_decl ',' redim_decl_list
                         | redim_decl;

redim_decl: extended_id '(' expr_list ')';

/* if statement */

if_stmt: 'if' expr 'then' new_line block_stmt_list else_stmt_list 'end' 'if' new_line
                         | 'if' expr 'then' inline_stmt else_opt end_if_opt new_line;

else_stmt_list: ('elseif' expr 'then' new_line block_stmt_list else_stmt_list
                         | 'elseif' expr 'then' inline_stmt new_line else_stmt_list
                         | 'else' inline_stmt new_line
                         | 'else' new_line block_stmt_list)?;

else_opt: ('else' inline_stmt)?;
end_if_opt : ('end' 'if')?;

/* with statement */

with_stmt: 'with' expr new_line block_stmt_list 'end' 'with' new_line;

/* loop statement */

loop_stmt: 'do' loop_type expr new_line block_stmt_list 'loop' new_line
                         | 'do' new_line block_stmt_list 'loop' loop_type expr new_line
                         | 'do' new_line block_stmt_list 'loop' new_line
                         | 'while' expr new_line block_stmt_list 'wend' new_line;

loop_type: 'while' | 'until';

/* for statement */

for_stmt: 'for' extended_id '=' expr 'to' expr step_opt new_line block_stmt_list 'next' new_line
                         | 'for' 'each' extended_id 'in' expr new_line block_stmt_list 'next' new_line;

step_opt: ('step' expr)?;

/* select statement */

select_stmt: 'select' 'case' expr new_line cast_stmt_list 'end' 'select' new_line;

cast_stmt_list: ('case' expr_list nl_opt block_stmt_list cast_stmt_list
                         | 'case' 'else' nl_opt block_stmt_list)?;

nl_opt: new_line?;

expr_list: expr ',' expr_list | expr;

/*===== rules: expressions =====*/

sub_safe_expr: sub_safe_imp_expr;

sub_safe_imp_expr: sub_safe_imp_expr 'imp' eqv_expr | sub_safe_eqv_expr;

sub_safe_eqv_expr: sub_safe_eqv_expr 'eqv' xor_expr
                         | sub_safe_xor_expr;

sub_safe_xor_expr: sub_safe_xor_expr 'xor' or_expr
                         | sub_safe_or_expr;

sub_safe_or_expr: sub_safe_or_expr 'or' and_expr
                         | sub_safe_and_expr;

sub_safe_and_expr       : sub_safe_and_expr 'and' not_expr
                         | sub_safe_not_expr;

sub_safe_not_expr       : 'not' not_expr
                         | sub_safe_compare_expr;



sub_safe_compare_expr   : sub_safe_compare_expr 'is' concat_expr
                         | sub_safe_compare_expr 'is' 'not' concat_expr
                         | sub_safe_compare_expr '>=' concat_expr
                         | sub_safe_compare_expr '=>' concat_expr
                         | sub_safe_compare_expr '<=' concat_expr
                         | sub_safe_compare_expr '=<' concat_expr
                         | sub_safe_compare_expr '>'  concat_expr
                         | sub_safe_compare_expr '<'  concat_expr
                         | sub_safe_compare_expr '<>' concat_expr
                         | sub_safe_compare_expr '='  concat_expr
                         | sub_safe_concat_expr;

sub_safe_concat_expr    : sub_safe_concat_expr '&' add_expr
                         | sub_safe_add_expr;

sub_safe_add_expr       : sub_safe_add_expr '+' mod_expr
                         | sub_safe_add_expr '-' mod_expr
                         | sub_safe_mod_expr;

sub_safe_mod_expr       : sub_safe_mod_expr 'mod' int_div_expr
                         | sub_safe_int_div_expr;

sub_safe_int_div_expr    : sub_safe_int_div_expr '\\' mult_expr
                         | sub_safe_mult_expr;

sub_safe_mult_expr      : sub_safe_mult_expr '*' unary_expr
                         | sub_safe_mult_expr '/' unary_expr
                         | sub_safe_unary_expr;

sub_safe_unary_expr     : '-' unary_expr
                         | '+' unary_expr
                         | sub_safe_exp_expr;

sub_safe_exp_expr       : sub_safe_value '^' exp_expr
                         | sub_safe_value;

sub_safe_value         : const_expr
                         | left_expr
                         | '(' expr ')';

expr                 : imp_expr;

imp_expr              : imp_expr 'imp' eqv_expr
                         | eqv_expr;

eqv_expr              : eqv_expr 'eqv' xor_expr
                         | xor_expr;

xor_expr              : xor_expr 'xor' or_expr
                         | or_expr;

or_expr               : or_expr 'or' and_expr
                         | and_expr;

and_expr              : and_expr 'and' not_expr
                         | not_expr;

not_expr              : 'not' not_expr
                         | compare_expr;

compare_expr          : compare_expr 'is' concat_expr
                         | compare_expr 'is' 'not' concat_expr
                         | compare_expr '>=' concat_expr
                         | compare_expr '=>' concat_expr
                         | compare_expr '<=' concat_expr
                         | compare_expr '=<' concat_expr
                         | compare_expr '>'  concat_expr
                         | compare_expr '<'  concat_expr
                         | compare_expr '<>' concat_expr
                         | compare_expr '='  concat_expr
                         | concat_expr;

concat_expr           : concat_expr '&' add_expr
                         | add_expr;

add_expr              : add_expr '+' mod_expr
                         | add_expr '-' mod_expr
                         | mod_expr;

mod_expr              : mod_expr 'mod' int_div_expr
                         | int_div_expr;

int_div_expr           : int_div_expr '\\' mult_expr
                         | mult_expr;

mult_expr             : mult_expr '*' unary_expr
                         | mult_expr '/' unary_expr
                         | unary_expr;

unary_expr            : '-' unary_expr
                         | '+' unary_expr
                         | exp_expr;

exp_expr              : value '^' exp_expr
                         | value;

value                : const_expr
                         | left_expr
                         | '(' expr ')';

const_expr            : bool_literal
                         | int_literal
                         | float_literal
                         | string_literal
                         | nothing;

bool_literal          : 'true'
                         | 'false';

int_literal           : DIGIT+;

nothing              : 'nothing'
                         | 'null'
                         | 'empty';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grammar defines "Literals" in the parser section. Note that ANTLR treats every lower case rule as parser rule (upper case rules are lexer rules).

Your small problem part may be solved like this:

```
FLOAT_LITERAL
  : DIGIT* '.' DIGIT+ ( 'e' PLUS_OR_MINUS? DIGIT+ )?
  | DIGIT+ 'e' PLUS_OR_MINUS? DIGIT+;
LETTER
  : [a-z];
```

The ANTLR lexer prefers the longest matching rule (if two rules are in conflict, it prefers the first defined one). Both rules are completely disjunct so the sequence of definition is not relevant (its just more readable to define the more complex rules above the basic ones).

You can extend the second definition by upper case Characters:

```
LETTER
  : [a-zA-Z];
```

To solve the overall problem of your grammar, you will need a complete rewriting of your grammar. Most rules of the `terminals` section should be lexer rules. However the terminals sections seems overly populated so that it could also be that some rules are workarounds for non existent parser rules.

Comment: That makes sense :) I wasn't sure if you could have lexer rules made up of other lexer rules or not unless they were fragments.  Thanks.